# Loop Changing to Matrix then Running tests

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe with ~9000 rows of human coded data in it, two coders per item so about 4500 unique pairs. I want to break the dataset into each of these pairs, so ~4500 dataframes, run a kripp.alpha on the scores that were assigned, and then save those into a coder sheet I have made. I cannot get the loop to work to do this.

I can get it to work individually, using this:

```
example.m <- as.matrix(example.m)
s <- kripp.alpha(example.m)
example$alpha <- s$value
```

However, when trying a loop I am getting either "Error in get(v) : object 'NA' not found" when running this:

```
for (i in items) {
  v <- i
  v <- v[c("V1","V2")]
  v <- assign(v, as.matrix(get(v)))
  s <- kripp.alpha(v)
  i$alpha <- s$value
}
```

Or am getting "In i$alpha <- s$value : Coercing LHS to a list" when running:

```
for (i in items) {
  i.m <- i[c("V1","V2")]
  i.m <- as.matrix(i.m)
  s <- kripp.alpha(i.m)
  i$alpha <- s$value
}
```

Here is an example set of data. Items is a list of individual dataframes.

```
l <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(4,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,1),nrow=2))
t <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(4,3,4,3,1,1,3,3,1,3,1,1),nrow=2))

items <- c("l","t")
```

I am sure this is a basic question, but what I want is for each file, i, to add a column with the alpha score at the end. Thanks!

Comment: This is not really a reproducible example, so tough to test any proposed solutions.  However, it looks like in the second chunk you might be able to change the last line to: `i$alpha <- unlist(s$value)`

Comment: Is your items in `for(i in items)` is a data.frame or a list of data.frames? If it is the former, then your `i` will be looping each column of the item, which makes `v <- v[c("col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8")]` a nonsensical command.

Comment: Also, stackoverflow is not a debugging or troubleshooting service. Provide a reproducible example of what your starting data look like and what end result you wish to achieve. There are lots of great minds here that can help to come out with better solution than a basic loop.

Comment: Edited with a sample set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with scoping and extracting names from objects when referenced through strings. You'd need to `eval()` some of your object to make your current approach work.

Here's another solution

```
library("irr") # For kripp.alpha

# Produce the data
l <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(4,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,1),nrow=2))
t <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(4,3,4,3,1,1,3,3,1,3,1,1),nrow=2))

# Collect the data as a list right away
items <- list(l, t)
```

Now you can `sapply()` directly over the elements in the list.

```
sapply(items, function(v) {
  kripp.alpha(as.matrix(v[c("V1","V2")]))$value
})
```

which produces

```
[1]  0.0 -0.5
```